# (pinia, vuex) Why can't I access states and getters in main.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, pinia

**Solved**
Although not exactly my solution to this problem, the answer given below from @Po Wen Chen was helpful but it doesn't work exactly as I want it to. data in the form of proxy continues to come, this is not important, the conditions are met.

The main problem was that every time the page was refreshed, the states were null, so their values were flying. After we searched, my states became permanent with the library named `pinia-plugin-persistedstate`.
**Solved**

I did as it is written in the documentation, but instead of receiving a user data, I am getting a proxy type data.

[Documentation of pinia describing how to use store outside of component](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/outside-component-usage.html#single-page-applications)

The account store performs the registration and login of the users, that is, the auth processes.

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

const useAccountStore = defineStore("account", {
  state: () => ({
    user: null,
    returnUrl: null
  }),
  getters: {
    isLoggedIn: state => (state.user ? true : false),
    getUser: state => state.user,
  },
  actions: {
    async init() {
      console.log('run the init')
      this.fetchUser()
    },
    async registerUser(user) {
      await axios.post("/account/register", {user})
    },
    async login(credentials) {
      const user = await axios.post("/account/session", credentials)

      this.user = user.data
    },
    async logout() {
      await axios.delete("/account/session")

      this.user = null
    },
    async fetchUser() {
      const user = await axios.get("/account")

      this.user = user.data
    },
  },
})

export { useAccountStore };
```

In main.js

```js
import antd from "ant-design-vue"
import "ant-design-vue/dist/antd.css"
import axios from "axios"
import { createPinia } from "pinia"
import { createApp } from "vue"
import App from "./app.vue"
import { router } from "./router"
import { useAccountStore } from "./store/account.store"
// import './assets/main.css'

axios.defaults.baseURL = import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true

createApp(App)
  .use(createPinia())
  .use(router)
  .use(antd)
  .mount("#app")

useAccountStore().init()

router.beforeEach(async (to) => {
  // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page 
  const publicPages = ['/login', '/register'];
  const authRequired = !publicPages.includes(to.path);
  const authStore = useAccountStore();

  console.log('authStore.isLoggedIn', authStore)

  if (authRequired && !authStore.user) {
      authStore.returnUrl = to.fullPath;
      return '/login';
  }
});
```

I press the authStore to console and it comes back to me as a proxy.

[return the proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgNFZ.png)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please DO NOT post code screenshots, we have code blocks in the Wysiwyg for a reason, and please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is the problem with this code? Because a proxy isn't, it's just JS feature that makes Vue reactivity work. Read https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html

Comment: Yes. It's a proxy. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Although not exactly my solution to this problem, the answer given below from @Po Wen Chen was helpful but it doesn't work exactly as I want it to. data in the form of proxy continues to come, this is not important, the conditions are met.

The main problem was that every time the page was refreshed, the states were null, so their values were flying. After we searched, my states became permanent with the library named pinia-plugin-persistedstate.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).